# C++ why is my class still abstract?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I'm sure its something simple on my part, but I can't figure out why my compiler thinks one of my classes is abstract. Here's the situation:

I have an abstract base class like so:

```
class AnimatedDraw
{
public:
    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window) = 0;
    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Shader shader) = 0;
    virtual void Update(sf::Clock &time) = 0;
};
```

And I inherit from it as so:

```
class ScreenLayer : public AnimatedDraw
{
public:
    ScreenLayer(void);

    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window);

    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Shader &shader);

    virtual void Update(sf::Clock &clock);

    ~ScreenLayer(void);
};
```

for reference, the ScreenLayer.cpp file is as follows:

```
#include "ScreenLayer.h"
ScreenLayer::ScreenLayer(void)
{
}
void ScreenLayer::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
}
void ScreenLayer::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Shader &shader)
{
}
void ScreenLayer::Update(sf::Clock &clock)
{
}
ScreenLayer::~ScreenLayer(void)
{
}
```

However, when I try to use my derived class (i.e. `AnimatedDraw *testDrawer = new ScreenLayer;` ) my compiler complains the ScreenLayer is abstract. Changing AnimatedDraw to ScreenLayer was also invalid for the same reason. I overwrote all the abstract function on my base class didn't I? I'm not sure why it's being seen as abstract. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: @user: I am almost certain that your compiler will give you an error that says which method causes the class to be abstract.

Comment: Also declare a virtual destructor in the base class.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your base class declaration doesn't have an ampersand after sf::Shader:

```
virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Shader shader) = 0;
```

The derived class has, hence it's a different overloaded function.

Comment: Technically speaking, function in derived class hides one in base class, not overloads.

Comment: woops.. sorry I didn't see that. Thanks for finding the mistake

Comment: It's a mistake I've made as well, that's how I knew what to look for :)

Comment: In C++0x, you will be able to add attributes to your functions, such as `override` (in the Derived class) for the compiler to check that your method actually overrides something and warns you otherwise.