# Inheritance work with one class, but not with another

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml

I created two classes: Player, Bullet. Both inherit from same SFML classes [sf::Drawable](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Drawable.php), and sf::Transformable.

First class:

```
class Player :
    public sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable
{
public:
    Player();
    ~Player();

    enum Direction {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT};

    void update();
    void move(Direction dir);
    float getRotation();
    sf::Vector2f getPosition();
    void shoot();
    bool moveStatus;

private:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture texture;

    float speed;
    size_t frame;

    sf::Clock animClock;
    sf::Clock shootTime;

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
};
```

Second class:

```
class Bullet :
    public sf::Drawable, sf::Transformable
{
public:
    Bullet(float rot, sf::Vector2f pos);
    ~Bullet();

    void update();
    float getRotation();
    sf::Vector2f getPosition();
    void move(float x, float y);

private:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture texture;

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
};
```

I have a problem with `virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;`. In Player class it's working, but in Bullet class isn't.

The linker returns 2 errors:
[image]
I tried to add ampersand to definition before `states` but then Bullet has become an abstract class.

Comment: I saw the question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416048/c-why-is-my-class-still-abstract). But my declaration is correct and in one class it works but in another not

Comment: You missed to provide _all of the declarations_ in your 2nd class to satisfy the interface declarations.

Comment: Do you have a definition of `draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states)` in Bullet? Where is the body of this function?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is a linker error, the problem has nothing to do with classes being abstract. There are no abstract classes in OP's code.

Comment: Where is the actual definition of draw function?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are missing the actual **implementation** of the `draw` method in your `Bullet` class.

Without code it's hard to say, but you are either missing it completely, or maybe have a typo in the signature.