# Troubleshooting 'invalid abstract return type'

Tags: c++, g++

I have an abstract class `A` with about 20 pure virtual functions, and subclasses `B` and `C` which implement all of them.  They work great.

I just wrote another non-abstract class `D` that's also a subclass of `A`.  I *thought* I provided an implementation for all of the pure functions inside `D`, but when I try instantiating the class g++ 4.9.2 gives either the error "cannot declare variable `d` to be of abstract type `D`" or "invalid abstract return type `D`" (depending on the context).

I'm guessing that either:

1. I forgot one of the methods
2. The type signature on one of the methods is wrong.

I've gone through and starred at the code and I don't see either of these being the case.  However, I suspect that I just missed something.  Now, I could post all of the code here and ask others to stare at it and find the problem.  That's what happened here: [C++ why is my class still abstract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416048/c-why-is-my-class-still-abstract) Namely, the code was almost correct except for a teeny missing ampersand that caused the type signatures to differ and thus an error.  But I don't really want to post my code because it's long, templated, not self-contained, and mostly irrelevant to the actual problem.

Instead, I would like a general solution/tool for solving this problem.  It should be very easy for the compiler to automatically tell me *which* method is causing the problem (i.e. which method of the abstract base class isn't overridden in `D`).  Is there a flag for g++ that could help me out?  Another tool?  Another idea?  I'd rather not upgrade from g++ 4.9 (because that will take quite a bit of work for the project) but I would be willing to if it gives me better error messages for situations like this.

Comment: Go over all the overriding member function of `D` and add the [override specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). That should pin-point accidental overloads. It's a good idea to get in the habit of using it anyway.

Comment: Your compiler isnt telling you WHY `D` is still abstract? Usually compilers will just tell you the abstract method(s) that haven't been overriden, you shouldn't need to enable a flag to get that output.

Comment: Doesn't print your compiler which functions are missing? [g++ does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a614a6b5715b4df)

Comment: @RemyLebeau tkausl That's what I expected too, but it seems g++4.9.2 doesn't.  It looks like the version on that site has runs 8.2.  Maybe I will have to upgrade after all :/

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks, I'll give that a shot!

Comment: @StoryTeller Remy I've put `override` on all the appropriate methods (thanks for that tip by the way, I'll try and incorporate that whenever I override methods from now on) but got no new errors.  I guess that narrows it down to just missing a function?

Comment: That would be only remaining thing I can think of.

Comment: Also, any thoughts on why this question may have been downvoted?  I believe I asked it clearly and did research on it.

Comment: Objectively, and I didn't downvote, this question is more of an abstract discussion than a well-defined, narrow, problem. Some would say it doesn't fit the format.

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for that feedback.

Comment: Turns out it was a missing function.  Thanks for the tips guys.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution seems to be upgrading to recent g++ for a real error message.

A best practice and helpful technique is to add override annotations to help identify any methods whose type signatures are incorrect.